# jQuery append: can't get the quotes right

Tags: javascript, jquery, quotes, quoting

I'm trying to add some HTML to a div, but I can't get the quotes right... This is what I thought would work, but doesn't...:

```
success: function (data) {
id = data.photo_id;
$("#successtext").append('<a href="https://www.theurl.com/' + id + '" data-role="button">The link</a><a href="#" data-role="button">Log Out</a>');
$("#success").show();
$("#uploading").hide();
$("#turn").hide();
turnable = 0;
}
```

As you can see, this is part of an Ajax calls. Note that the append does work, just not with the right button markup.

Note: the first link links to, for example, https://www.theurl.com/223424324

What am I doing wrong, and why? Thanks!

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Not an error, just bad mark-up. The a href should be a button (jQuery mobile -> data-role="button"), but it's just showing two text-hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have extra quote at `www.theurl.com/"'+id+'"`, change to:

```
$("#successtext").append('<a href="https://www.theurl.com/'+id+'" data-role="button">The link</a><a href="#" data-role="button">Log Out</a>');
```

**Update::** call `.trigger('create')` after appending

```
$("#successtext")
    .append('<a href="https://www.theurl.com/'+id+'" data-role="button">The link</a><a href="#" data-role="button">Log Out</a>')
    .trigger('create');
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j45o3thv/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your code, but it doesn't fix my problem. I still get text-hyperlinks, not buttons. It's like it loses the data-role or something... (buttons do work without this append-thing, though).

Comment: @binoculars at what point are you appending tag, could you show some more code..!

Comment: @binoculars you need to call .trigger('create') after appending tag in order to make it work for dynamic addition.. see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Existing:

```
 '<a href="https://www.theurl.com/"'+id+'"
```

You're ending your quotes for `href` attribute before adding the `id` to it and after adding `id` you're adding the quotes again, which is breaking the things.

Correct:

```
'<a href="https://www.theurl.com/'+id+'"
```

The basic thing is that when you're appending text after you're ajax request then jquery mobile is not creating its own DOM element around your link to look it like a button. So for that we need to allow jquery mobile to create its DOM after appending the text.
Try below function.

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#successtext').trigger('create');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/ykwbgh1c/)

Comment: Doesn't fix my problem, unfortunately (cf. my response to Sudhir's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

JS :

```
$('#successtext').append('<a href="https://www.theurl.com/'+id+'" data-role="button">The link</a><a href="#" data-role="button">Log Out</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/9wv0rhsc/)

As others have pointed out, the issue is that your href has two closing quotation marks (basically `href="...""`). It does however highlight the issue you can run into with manually stuffing long html fragments into JS strings before appending them with jQuery. Consider instead treating the html elements as objects, and constructing them as such with jQuery:

```
$("#successtext").append($("<a />", {
    href: "https://www.theurl.com/" + id,
    "data-role": "button",
    text: "The link"
}), $("<a />", {
    href: "#",
    "data-role": "button",
    text: "Log Out"
}));
```

Comment: Never thought of that, certainly something I'll keep in mind in the future. Thanks! Didn't fix my problem though, the fix was I had to put `.trigger('create')` after the append.